# How to pass parameters from url to service Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a case like this and don't know how to do it properly. I take the parameters from the url and want to pass this parameter to the service. But the service initializes faster than I can get the parameter. What to do in this situation?

**Component**

```
id!: string;

  constructor(
    public someService: SomeService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    const id = this.route.parent?.parent?.snapshot.params['id'];

    if (!id) {
      return;
    }

    this.id = id;
    this.someService.id = this.id;
}
```

**Service**

```
    id!: string;
    data$ = this.getSomeData$(this.id);
    
      private traces$ = this.data$.pipe(
        // some operators
      );
    
      private otherTraces$ = this.data$.pipe(
        // some operators
      );
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Move the get id logic to `ngOnInit()` method. And it's weird that you pass and directly assign the id in the service. The `id` field in Service should be `public` in order to allow to set the value. Would recommend passing the value through the method.

Comment: I did this but in the `traces$` and `otherTraces$` variable I get an error that the `data$` is undefined

Comment: Could you please share the code of `getSomeData$` method?

Comment: getSomeData$ - this is a normal get request

Comment: The problem is that the service still fails to get the ID, i.e. it gets undefined

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will move the logic for retrieving the id on the [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence), so you will get the id after the view init.

Then, in your service, I will probably create a setter for the id in order to trigger the `getSomeData`. (But I don't know what you would achieve).

Something like:

```js
 private _id: string;

 public set id(id: id) {
   this._id = id;
   this.getSomeData$(id);
 }
```

Comment: I did this but in the `traces$` and `otherTraces$` variable I get an error that the `data$` is undefined

Comment: who is `data$`?